# Why did this question's title avoid the word filter?

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, title, quality-filter

Recently I came across [the question, "Java programming homework help"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080314/java-programming-homework) (need 10K rep to see the link).

It was tagged C++ for no reason so I untagged it, but when I came to submit my edit I came across an interesting conundrum. At the time, it had "help" in the title, which is unlawful now, so the system rejected my edit.

However, the guy somehow had already asked the question with "help" in the title and dodged the filter. I didn't think to check the title because he had only just asked it- it's not like, one from before the filter existed or anything.
So I'm currently concluding that the filter must be inconsistently applied.

Comment: If it's blocked [the block isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3ahelp)

Comment: I *think* `help` is only blocked if it's at the beginning of the title, but I can't find a reference for that right now.

Comment: _help_ seems too broad; I've seen people asking for assistance in preparing their [CHM files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) before...

Comment: That does not explain why it stopped us from submitting our edits if we left "help" in the title though.

Answer (score 5):

This is the current regex we are using:

`\b((?:question(?! mark)|doubt|^help|help with|problem)\b|help[?!. ]*?$|\s*?!+\s*?$)` ... note, it is subject to change.

We only block `help` at the begining of the title or `help with`,`help?`, `help.` and `help!` anywhere in the title.

The old regex had an issue with trailing spaces.

If we need to improve or expand the block please post a new meta question with data to back up the reasoning.

Comment: So why does removing the C++ tag from the original version give the "Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:" message? I just tried it by clicking [the edit link against the first version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10080314/revisions) and saw the same message.

Comment: because the original title was `Java programming homework help ` notice the trailing space, if we want to clean the regex up I am fine to do so

Comment: Bit early in the day to be looking at RegExs but from pasting into RegEx buddy I think your description of the behaviour is not correct. It blocks `help` followed by zero or more of `?!.` at the end of the string only. i.e. `help!` in the middle of a string is not blocked.  I guess changing the bit at the end to `help[?!.\s]*?` should deal with any trailing spaces (that presumably get trimmed after validation) if that's the desired behaviour.

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  If the edit is blocked, then the  original post should have been blocked, but *it wasn't*.  Clearly there are 2 different filters at play and the code is not *DRY*.

Comment: I fixed the regex so it blocks trailing spaces

Comment: @BrockAdams - It makes sense to me if the OP submitted with a trailing space thus bypassing the validation then later this trailing space gets trimmed.

Comment: @MartinSmith:  Good point.  Burned by whitespace trimming again.  **However**, this is still effectively 2 different filters.  If WS is going to be trimmed, it should be done before filters are applied.  I imagine this bug will arise again, otherwise.

Comment: Looks like this regex is solving a [question about "question" in the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107326/what-should-we-do-with-posts-with-question-in-their-title) I posted last year. Can you post some answer there, and mark it as status complete?